# how can i fix this package installation error and install require hardevine/shoppingcart for my laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, shopping-cart

```
PS F:\web\Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master>
PS F:\web\Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master>
PS F:\web\Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master> composer require hardevine/shoppingcart
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^3.1 for hardevine/shoppingcart
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update hardevine/shoppingcart
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CanBeBought" was found in both "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/bumbummen99/shoppingcart/src\CanBeBought.php" and "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/hardevine/shoppingcart/src\CanBeBought.php", the first will be used.                                                                                                                         
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Cart" was found in both "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/bumbummen99/shoppingcart/src\Cart.php" and "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/hardevine/shoppingcart/src\Cart.php", the first will be used.                                                                                                                                              
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem" was found in both "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/bumbummen99/shoppingcart/src\CartItem.php" and "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/hardevine/shoppingcart/src\CartItem.php", the first will be used.                                                                                                                                  
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItemOptions" was found in both "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/bumbummen99/shoppingcart/src\CartItemOptions.php" and "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/hardevine/shoppingcart/src\CartItemOptions.php", the first will be used.                                                                                                             
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Contracts\Buyable" was found in both "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/bumbummen99/shoppingcart/src\Contracts\Buyable.php" and "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/hardevine/shoppingcart/src\Contracts\Buyable.php", the first will be used.                                                                                                       
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Exceptions\CartAlreadyStoredException" was found in both "F:/web/Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master/vendor/bumbummen99/shoppingcart/src\Exceptions\CartAlrDiscovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: livewire/livewireDiscovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collisionDiscovered Package: sven/artisan-view
Package manifest generated successfully.84 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!Found 11 security vulnerability advisories affecting 4 packages.
Run composer audit for a full list of advisories.
PS F:\web\Laravel-Advance-Ecommerce-master>
```

im trying to install this package and create shopping cart for my laravel project

Comment: which ```laravel``` version you are using

Answer (score 2):

the package you're trying to install [`hardevine/shoppingcart`](https://github.com/hardevine/LaravelShoppingcart) and the package that already exists in your installation [`bumbummen99/LaravelShoppingcart`](https://github.com/bumbummen99/LaravelShoppingcart) are both a fork of the same original package [`Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart`](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) which is not compatible with the latest version of laravel. You can only use one of them.

Or if you have the patience, make your own fork that merges the functionalities of both forks or just use bumbummen99's which is the most up to date one. Depends on your needs and what those packages add to the original one.

Comment: thank you so much Sri. im new to the laravel.  your advice is correct and following  your instruction i fixed my project problem